# How to return the values in local symbol table in kotlin (if it exists)?

Tags: python, kotlin

I am looking for an equivalent function similar to locals() in Python.

I want to use such a function inside another function:

```
fun fun1(..){
    //call locals() here to get local symbol table.
}
```

How can I implement this?

For context i am trying to implement this in kotlin ->

https://pastecode.io/s/jogze068

```
# Create the Account class
def make_account_class():
    """Return the Account class, which has deposit and withdraw methods."""
    interest = 0.02
    def __init__(self, account_holder):
        self['set']('holder', account_holder)
        self['set']('balance', 0)
    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Increase the account balance by amount and return the new balance."""
        new_balance = self['get']('balance') + amount
        self['set']('balance', new_balance)
        return self['get']('balance')
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """Decrease the account balance by amount and return the new balance."""
        balance = self['get']('balance')
        if amount > balance:
            return 'Insufficient funds'
        self['set']('balance', balance - amount)
        return self['get']('balance')
    return make_class(locals())
```

Im trying to translate from python to kotlin and trying to figure out what i can use instead of locals()

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). This is definitely a wrong approach. What are you trying to ultimately achieve?

Comment: I doubt this is possible in Kotlin. Most statically typed, compiled languages don't provide this kind of functionality.

Comment: Unlike Python, where the list of local variables can be dynamically changed, you always know for certain what local variables there are, just by inspecting the source code. There is no need for such a function.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/parameters.html